# Redis 4.0 mixed AOF+RDB

Tags: database, redis, nosql

In redis 4.0, there is a new mixed RDB+AOF discussed [enter link description here](http://rtfcode.com/xref/redis-4.0.6/00-RELEASENOTES/) in the redis change log:

> - Mixed RDB-AOF format. If enabled the new format is used when rewriting the AOF file: the rewrite uses the more compact and faster to generate RDB format, and an AOF stream is appended to the file. This allows faster rewrites and reloads when using the AOF persistence.

I would like to know how to setup this config in the redis config file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [1]:

```
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
```

REFENERANCE
[1] https://github.com/leonchen83/redis-replicator#341-mixed-file-format